# Removing index.php in url using .htaccess but failed

Tags: codeigniter

I have created .htaccess to remove index.php in url. After logout I redirect('auth'); but in the url appear index.php i.e. http://localhost/myhems/index.php/auth

Anyone know why?

Comment: but the adress http://localhost/myhems/auth work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what operating system your are working on, but make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled if you are on `linux` then follow these steps, here is the simplest `.htaccess` rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Save this file in your `FCPATH`, then go to your `config.php` under `application/config` and make sure to set the `base_url` in:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myhems/';
```

and delete the value in `index.php` in:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Thanks Sherif Salah... After delete the value index.php it seem ok.