# Display all images in a folder in Codeigniter View

Tags: codeigniter-3

I'm using Codeigniter 3 for my websites and want to display all the images in a folder. I used the following code but occurred an error.

```
$dir = base_url()."assets/stories/".$story["id_stories"]; // Your Path to folder
//For the test purpose - It is working properly.
echo $dir;

$files = array_diff(scandir(FCPATH .'assets/stories/'.$story['id_stories']), array('.', '..'));

foreach($files as $file) { 
  echo '<img src="'.$file. '" />'; 
}
```

And I got the error message.

Severity: Warning

Message: scandir(https://www.readphotos.com/assets/stories/4): failed to open dir: not implemented

Filename: story/view.php

Line Number: 148

Comment: try to use `glob()` php  function

Comment: Please can you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
$path = FCPATH .'assets'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stories'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$story['id_stories'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
foreach (glob($path."*.*") as $file) {
    echo '<img src="'.site_url('assets'.'/'.'stories'.'/'.$story["id_stories"].'/'.$file). '" />';
}
```

Comment: With FCPATH it returns url. but unable to see the images.

Comment: What do you mean it returns url? .. oh wait my bad i'll update the code .. it should work fine now!

Comment: Is it any way to retrieve only the file name? then it can add to that echo line. Now it returns something like this https://www.my_web_site.com/assets/stories/4//home/primary_domain/public_html/my_web_site.com/assets/stories/4/1.jpg"

Comment: Aha its a different issue now .. set you `base_url` in you `config.php`

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56425891/removing-index-php-in-url-using-htaccess-but-failed/56426775?r=SearchResults&s=2|21.4042#56426775

Comment: duplicate `base_url` means it is not set correctly.

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'https://www.my_web_site.com'; and $config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: I'm pretty sure my code above is ok but your issue now is with base_url .. remove site_url and try again ..`'<img src="'.'assets'.'/'.'stories'.'/'.$story["id_stories"].'/'.$file. '" />`

Comment: I'm trying to use another method. But I'm pretty sure that no error with your code. and thank you very much for your continuous support to solve the matter. Highly appreciate it. Thanks again.